# Joining a dataframe onto another dataframe that is the same content summarized by a categorical variable

Tags: r

Using library(tidyverse).

I have a very large dataframe structured like so (thousands of observations grouped into 31 levels by STATION):

```
 A tibble: 31 x 5
   STATION     NAME       LONGITUDE LATITUDE ELEVATION
   <fct>       <list>     <list>    <list>   <list>   
 1 US1ORLA0001 <chr [31]> <NULL>    <NULL>   <NULL>   
 2 US1ORLA0003 <chr [31]> <NULL>    <NULL>   <NULL>   
 3 US1ORLA0004 <chr [31]> <NULL>    <NULL>   <NULL>   
 4 US1ORLA0005 <chr [31]> <NULL>    <NULL>   <NULL>   
 5 US1ORLA0031 <chr [31]> <NULL>    <NULL>   <NULL>   
 6 US1ORLA0040 <chr [31]> <NULL>    <NULL>   <NULL>   
 7 US1ORLA0050 <chr [31]> <NULL>    <NULL>   <NULL>   
 8 US1ORLA0076 <chr [31]> <NULL>    <NULL>   <NULL>   
 9 US1ORLA0088 <chr [31]> <NULL>    <NULL>   <NULL>   
10 US1ORLA0089 <chr [31]> <NULL>    <NULL>   <NULL>   
 ... with 21 more rows
```

I also have a summarized version of this data set which I created with the following code:

```
summary <- raw %>%
  group_by(STATION) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(count))
```

resulting in this:

```
# A tibble: 31 x 2
   STATION     count
   <fct>       <int>
 1 USC00353995 17136
 2 USC00351324 14110
 3 USR0000OHIG 11610
 4 USR0000OVIL 11500
 5 USR0000OGOO 10855
 6 USC00352972 10068
 7 USR0000ODUN  8286
 8 USC00355204  5880
 9 USR0000OCLY  4514
10 USC00352973  4295
# ... with 21 more rows
```

My goal is join the raw data tibble onto the summary data tibble in the fashion of a left_join which would result in a dataframe with one row per level (STATION factor), a COUNT column, and the rest of the columns from the raw data (name, long, lat, ele). Like so:

```
# A tibble: 31 x 6
# Groups:   STATION [31]
   STATION     count NAME                       LONGITUDE LATITUDE ELEVATION
   <fct>       <int> <fct>                          <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 USC00353995 17136 HONEYMAN STATE PARK, OR US     -124.     43.9      35.1
# ... with 30 more rows
```

I have tried to do that with the following command:

```
desired_output <- left_join(summary, raw, by = c("STATION" = "STATION"))
```

I would expect this to preserve the rows from x (1 for each level) and the columns from y. The problem is, it preserves all the rows form y too, so I end up with this:

```
# A tibble: 135,905 x 6
# Groups:   STATION [31]
   STATION     count NAME                       LONGITUDE LATITUDE ELEVATION
   <fct>       <int> <fct>                          <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 USC00353995 17136 HONEYMAN STATE PARK, OR US     -124.     43.9      35.1
 2 USC00353995 17136 HONEYMAN STATE PARK, OR US     -124.     43.9      35.1
 3 USC00353995 17136 HONEYMAN STATE PARK, OR US     -124.     43.9      35.1
 4 USC00353995 17136 HONEYMAN STATE PARK, OR US     -124.     43.9      35.1
 5 USC00353995 17136 HONEYMAN STATE PARK, OR US     -124.     43.9      35.1
 6 USC00353995 17136 HONEYMAN STATE PARK, OR US     -124.     43.9      35.1
 7 USC00353995 17136 HONEYMAN STATE PARK, OR US     -124.     43.9      35.1
 8 USC00353995 17136 HONEYMAN STATE PARK, OR US     -124.     43.9      35.1
 9 USC00353995 17136 HONEYMAN STATE PARK, OR US     -124.     43.9      35.1
10 USC00353995 17136 HONEYMAN STATE PARK, OR US     -124.     43.9      35.1
# ... with 135,895 more rows
```

which is not useful for my purposes.

What is the best approach to achieving this and similar outcomes? I am open to doing it totally differently (not using summarize, etc).

Comment: Subset your `y` tibble to just the columns you want to merge on (and those that you're merging by) and wrap it with `unique()` before the merge.  The "problem" is that you have a lot of repeat information in the `y` tibble you're merging on. OR just change your `summarize()` function to keep one value of each of the lat/lng/elv variables and then there's no need for a merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create a column 'count' on the original dataset and then apply `distinct` on the columns so that we get only one observation per group

```
library(dplyr)
raw %>% 
     group_by(STATION) %>% 
     mutate(count = n()) %>% 
     ungroup %>% 
     distinct(STATION, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

NOTE: In the input dataset, some of the columns are showed as `list`.  It is not clear based on the expected output showed

Comment: This is was my preferred solution as it was intuitive and I am using tidyverse.

Comment: Clarification: This code counts the number of total observations (across all columns) within the variable STATION, and creates a column containing that number for each station. But what is the best way to to count only the number of observations within a given column? I want to count the number of observations in the PRCP column, which is not included above, but is the relevant measure. @akrun

Comment: @ClaytonGlasser  If you need to count only the number of observations then `count(raw, STATION)`  for the `PRCP` it would be `count(raw, PRCP)` total observations per each group of PRCP

Answer (score 0):

The data.table way:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(raw)

raw[ , .(count=.N, lat=unique(LATITUDE), lng=unique(LONGITUDE)), by=STATION]
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I like that this tests the assumption that every observation in a given STATION factor is identical.